# ExpandableListView does not react and receive any click

Tags: android, events, listview

i ran into several problems when i try to insert an expandable-list into an existing activity (which is not derived from ExpandalbleListActivity).

The list does display like described in my XML layout but it does not react when i try to click / expand it.

For testing i inserted a button above the list and it receives the click. The list it self does NOT say clickable=false.

Code for the Expandable List:

```
<ExpandableListView
android:id="@+id/h_Zzwa_activity_listView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:groupIndicator="@color/transparent" android:clickable="true">
</ExpandableListView>
```

The code for initializing the list:

```
this.m_adapter = new HZzwaListAdapter(this, m_requests);
    listZzwa =  (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.h_Zzwa_activity_listView);
    listZzwa.setAdapter(this.m_adapter)
```

The Adapter (which is initiated and the group.. is called)

```
public class HZzwaListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{

private List<HMyMessage> items;
private Context myContext;


public HZzwaListAdapter(Context context)
{
    myContext = context;
}

public HZzwaListAdapter(Context context, List<HMyMessage> items)
{
    myContext = context;
    this.items = items;
}





@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.h_Zzwa_list_subitem,
                null);
    }

    HMyMessage message = items.get(childPosition);
    if (message != null)
    {
        TextView tvPlayerName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.h_Zzwalistitem_info_signText);
        tvPlayerName.setText(message.info.getSign());
    }
    return convertView;
}


@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
{
    return 1;
}


@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
{
    return null;
}


@Override
public int getGroupCount()
{
    return items.size();
}


@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
{
    return groupPosition;
}


@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.h_machching_list_item, null);
    }

    // Get item and set it into the view
    HMyMessage plan = (HMyMessage) items.get(groupPosition);
    if (plan != null)
    {
        TextView pname = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.h_Zzwalistitem_pname);
        TextView pF = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.h_Zzwalistitem_pText);

        if (pname != null)
        {
            pname.setText(plan.requester.getName());
        }
        if (pF != null)
        {
            pF.setText(plan.p + " unit  ");
        }
    }

    return convertView;

}


@Override
public boolean hasStableIds()
{
    return false;
}


@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

}
```

Even when i set a listener for the click or listItemClick event nothing happens.

Why? The same thing works very good with a usual list :/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked after i created a new group.xml and used this instead of the existing one

Comment: I found out that a layout which contains an imagebutton does not throw the events. REMOVE THE IMAGEBUTTON (use imageview instead) and it will work ... strange anyway...

Comment: @elCapitano You should update the answer with the comment above.

Answer (score 9):

Please add the child and group layout. With listview, there's a similar issue that listview not recieve `onItemClick` **when listview's item has button**. I met this issue before so i must implement onclick for each item in adapter.Check this [article ListView doesn’t respond to OnItemClickListener](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/listview-doesnt-respond-to-onitemclicklistener/) 
and [Issue 3414 **ListView doesn't receive OnItemClick/OnItemLongClick for items with clickable or focusable content**](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414)

**EDIT:** Put `android:focusable="false"` for the `Button` view or `EditText` view.

Comment: As you said, when it has a button, set `android:focusable="false"`

Comment: Adding focusable="false" Worked for me.

Comment: For ExpandableListView it also required android:clickable="false" on the button or other actionable view.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the appropriate listeners for an expandable list... They're not the same as for a normal list.

**Example:**

```
lv.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)  
    { 
        // Your code for click action here.
        return true; 
    } 
});
```

There's also a similar OnGroupClickListener.

For full details, check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: Thi Barak, thanks for your anwser, but this doesnt help. it seems that the expandableList does not receive anything :(

Comment: That's odd.  It works for me. But I'm using a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter, so maybe there's some difference in there, although I would think that the adapter would make no difference.

Comment: It realy seems that there is no event fired on click. I'll try a different approach. Thanks anyway .)

Answer (score 3):

I you are using some clickable components in your parent view (like Checkbox, ToggleButton, ImageButton...) then click event is not fired.

You can just set in your adapter, in `getGroupView`, click listener for convertView.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question , but i recieved the same issue from my program lately. My ExpandableListView was not responding and click events for the group clicks. So instead of implementing ExpandableListView.OnItemClickListener , i implemented ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener and it worked like charm. Hope this helps someone who recieves this problem later on.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface in your adapter.

```
public interface IExpandableListAdapter {
        void onItemClick(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded);
}
```

Add this onClickListener to your holder view

```
holderView.setOnClickListener(view -> iExpandableListAdapter.onItemClick(groupPosition, isExpanded));
```

Override Interface in your activity.

```
ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(context, list, (groupPosition, isExpanded) -> {
        if(isExpanded)
            expandableListView.collapseGroup(groupPosition);
        else
            expandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition); 
});
```

Now you can use click events of Button, ImageButton, etc. in your adapter.

Answer (score -1):

Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the base layout of whatever you're inflating that is no longer receiving the touch events as it should.